Can't drag files in Windows 11 VM in VirtualBox
I have Windows 11 installed in a VirtualBox VM, and for some reason, dragging things within the VM has stopped working. The fix that I've seen online where you power off the machine and go to the settings to set the pointing device to USB Tablet doesn't apply, because that's what that setting is already set to. How do I get drag functionality back in my VM?
Update: The Guest Additions have been installed and updated. Also, it turns out that it's just the ability to drag files and shortcuts that's not working. Other dragging operations (moving, resizing windows, drag to select, etc.) are working.
Update: I ended up abandoning that VM and working with an earlier one that I had cloned that one from. (No time to continue trying to fix this issue.) I'll close this question if nobody else does.

You installed the required extension within the host OS? [Edit] your question
